# configuring IP over infiband (IPoIB) in RHEL 7, scp speed

Tags: linux, infiniband

I am giving myself a crash course on infiniband in RHEL 7.9.  I have server(s) each having an HDR  ConnectX-6 card installed; this is in my lab and it's on a simple LAN where each server is connected to a Q8700 mlnx *switch* and for starters we just want basic network functionality over the infiniband so we can `ssh`, `scp` and create a basic nfs mount between servers.

- I have 5 servers, named  `c1` to `c5`
- Each is running RHEL 7.9 x86-64
- I did `mlnxofedinstall` from the `MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.2-1.0.4.0-rhel7.9-x86_64.iso` on each
- I did `systemctl enable openibd` on each followed by a reboot
- after that I manually `/etc/init.d/opensmd start` but only on `c1`
- using the NetworkManager gui in RHEL 7 I configured the `ib0` interface to be

  - 192.168.2.1  to  192.168.2.5  for c1..c5 respectively
  - subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 for each with no gateway specified.
  - if i do `ip ib0` it reports link speed of 100000

---

- is this all there is to it or am I missing a whole bunch of other stuff ?
- in doing `scp` over my copper 1gbps network, I always see a solid 112MB/sec; my take is 1000 mbps / 8 = 125 MBps then at 89.6% efficiency is 112 MBps.  If I assume 100000 mb/s on HDR infiniband datagram IPoIB being 100x faster I should see 11200 MB/sec ?

  - I am getting 262 MB/sec currently (scp'ing a 30gb tar file) having done only what's mentioned above.  Should I be getting better if so how much?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ib_ipoib module is loaded:

```
 lsmod | grep ipoib
ib_ipoib              124872  0
ib_cm                  53085  2 rdma_cm,ib_ipoib
ib_core               357959  8 rdma_cm,ib_cm,iw_cm,mlx5_ib,ib_umad,ib_uverbs,rdma_ucm,ib_ipoib
mlx_compat             55063  13 qedr,rdma_cm,ib_cm,iw_cm,auxiliary,mlx4_ib,mlx5_ib,ib_core,ib_umad,ib_uverbs,mlx5_core,rdma_ucm,ib_ipoib
```

If it isn't, you can load it via

```
modprobe ib_ipoib
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this test will not use your available bandwidth, since the bottleneck is your CPU.

SSH and thus scp is not able to use more than one vCPU.

Answer (score 0):

scp is great, but there is CPU overhead out the wahzoo!
setup a simple ftp and do the same test ... you should see significant speed improvements. Unless you have other I/O bottlenecks on your client or host systems.

I typically recommend to use the vendor's official drivers even if they are closed source, rather than the open-source, 3rd party drivers. They can make a HUGE difference with performance on your system.

The PCI bus can still only go so fast however. PCI-X has some different capabilities and limitations. Read the freaking manual and ensure you have your system and network adapter configured correctly!

Do everything right, plan your system configuration smartly and Infiniband will run like a bolt of lightening headed skyward!